# Best approach for frontend server rendering authentication with API backend

Tags: authentication, rust, jwt

I'm building a Rust web app using the classic backend/frontend servers.

**Backend**: will suply the frontend with data to be displayed, authorization services and other continuous jobs.

**Frontend**: will recieve data from the backend when requested, display it to the user and let the user navigate through the application.

When it comes to authorization, the frontend needs to know if the user is authenticated, so even if he tries to enter hostname/some_service, if he is not logged in, the application show redirect him to the login page.

On the other hand, th backend also needs to authenticate the cosumner trying to access its resources, so that any of it services can be accessed by other cosumers, not just my frontend.

I'm not sure how to handle this kind of situation:

When the user goes to the login page, no validation is required, since it's an entrypoint for the frontend app. When he tries to log in, the frontend issues a request to the backend server asking it to validate the given credentials. If it's OK, the backend needs to tell the frontend.

I'm trying to use JWT to send authorization information, but when/where should I generate the token? If the backend server generates and sends it to the frontend. the frontend cannot validade the token (in this case, the server has the secret to the JWT), so each and every request to every diferent route needs to call the backend authorization service to validate the token.
On the other hand, if the frontend generates the token, the frontend can validate it and does not need to request the server for each endpoint (besides the token refresh). But then, the backend cannot validate the token, so other authentication scheme would be needed for validation on other cosumers of the frontend.

I dont want to share the secret for the JWT between the frontend/backend.

Could you guys enlighten me on how to handle this? What is the best aproach

Bwt: using Rust for both front(yew) and back(actix)

Comment: I've used the crate 'actix-identity' in the past for this. The backend server can generate the token and send it to the frontend to be stored in a cookie (After logging in). After that you can use the actix-identity crate to have the server authorize the client (frontend) every time they visit a page (by validating the token).

Comment: I've looked into it. This would mean that I need two cookies: The JWT for the frontend validation and the actix identity for the backend validation, right?

And it looks like there is no persistent storage for the sessions (since identiy is build upon it). So I would need another service for persistence, like the example shown in the docs, using redis. I would not like that. If the identiy is stored directly in the cookies, there is no diference in creatng two JWT, one for the frontend validation and a second for the backend validation, which I want to avoid...